# How can I use boto to get content from an arbitrary S3 URL, or parse the URL to get its host, bucket, and key?

Tags: url, amazon-s3, boto

Does boto provide a way to parse S3 URLs? Get objects using arbitrary URLs rather than host, bucket and key names?

I've found the reverse operation -- [generate_url](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html?highlight=generate_url#boto.s3.connection.S3Connection.generate_url) -- and the various CallingFormats -- [OrdinaryCallingFormat](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html?highlight=generate_url#boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat), [ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html?highlight=generate_url#boto.s3.connection.ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat), [SubdomainCallingFormat](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html?highlight=generate_url#boto.s3.connection.SubdomainCallingFormat), and [VHostCallingFormat](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.6.0/ref/s3.html?highlight=generate_url#boto.s3.connection.VHostCallingFormat). It seems typical to take a bucket and key as input and generate URLs.

If I have URLs -- without auth credentials in the query parameters -- and I want to use boto to get the objects at those URLs, what's the best way?

See also a [similar, but more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132752/how-do-i-translate-an-aws-s3-url-into-a-bucket-name-for-boto).